# Axios PUT method throws error 500 but its updating the data

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hope someone can help me with this strange behavior my app is having.

I have two components. The first one renders a list of items (name and age) and the other component can edit those items.

The only way I have kind of make work an axios PUT request is passing my data to be updated as query string parameters.

```
const url = `${ROOT_URL}/test_endpoint?id${id}&name=${name}&age={age}`;

return axios.put(url)
.then(response =>{
  console.log(response.data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

That throws me error 500 but when I check my component where it renders the list of items the data is updated.

I have also tried the following:

```
const api ={
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
const { id,name,age } = data

return axios.put(`${ROOT_URL}/test_endpoint`, { id:id,name:name, age:age },{headers: api})
```

So, if I tried it this way it will still throw error 500 but it won't update anything. So only when passing the data as query string parameters it will work.

FYI: I'm using react, redux-thunk. The request its being made inside an action creator.

Comment: The 500 in general indicates that there is an issue/error on server side (where you are sending request). Did you check the logs on server side (test_endpoint). Can you see any errors there?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to the server side logs. I thought the error was because I was doing something wrong on my end since the update is actually being made only when sending the request with the data as query string parameters

Comment: You are able to test that (are you doing something wrong or not), by simply sending put request from some kind of other source, console, online tools or anything like that and check are you getting proper response with 200 ok and with data you need.

Comment: I've just tried it with https://www.hurl.it/ and with postman and everything was fine... response was code 200

Comment: If that is the case, you should focus on inspecting request you are sending with axios. Use network tools in order to inspect the request you are sending with axios and compare with the request you sent from hurl.it